# SAS; how to update a data set

Tags: database, sas

I have two datasets, lets say data1 and data2. Those data have same headers (therefore same amount columns).

```
data test
 set '\\(location on my pc)\data1`;
 keep column1 column2 column3; 
run;
```

How can I include numbers from from data2. I have (unsuccessfully) tried following:

```
data test
 set '\\(location on my pc)\data1`;
 set '\\(location on my pc)\data2`;
 keep column1 column2 column3; 
 run;
ANOTHER
data test
 set '\\(location on my pc)\data1` & '\\(location on my pc)\data2`;
 keep column1 column2 column3; 
 run;
```

Comment: The proc means statement in the last block of code is in an invalid form, unlike the earlier ones. Is that just a typo or are you trying to imply by that impossible syntax some type of action that you would like to be able to do?

Comment: i have now totally rephrased it so my actual problem appears better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to 'stack' the observations from multiple datasets then use a single SET statement.

```
data want ;
  set table1 table2 ;
run;
```

If they are already sorted by some key variable(s) then add a by statement and the observations will be interleaved.

```
data want;
  set table1 table2 ;
  by id;
run;
```

If you want to add observations to an existing dataset then you can use `PROC APPEND`.

```
proc append data=new base=old;
run;
```